# Solve issues with VueJS build and html-minifiy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, export, production

I'm trying to build my vuejs app, but I can't get it to work. I got the following error:

```
$ vue-cli-service build --mode production --dest dist --target app --modern --dashboard


-  Building legacy bundle for production...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors3:53:41 PM

 ERROR  Build failed with errors.


  Error: Parse Error: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcd  n.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css> 
    <link rel=" icon" href="favicon.ico"> 
    <title>AppTitle</title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <noscript> 
      <strong>Diese Seite funktioniert nur mit JavaScript. Bitte erlauben sie JavaScript, um die Seite richtig nutzen zu 
        können.</strong> 
    </noscript> 
    <div id="app"></div> 
    <!-- built files will be auto injected --> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chunk-vendors-legacy.c32ef6dd.js"></sc  ript><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app-legacy.f5ccfd09.js"></script>  </body> 
  </html>

  - htmlparser.js:240 new HTMLParser
    [apptitle]/[html-minifier]/src/htmlparser.js:240:13

  - htmlminifier.js:966 minify
    [apptitle]/[html-minifier]/src/htmlminifier.js:966:3

  - htmlminifier.js:1326 exports.minify
    [apptitle]/[html-minifier]/src/htmlminifier.js:1326:16

  - index.js:316 
    [apptitle]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:316:18
```

I think the issue is with html-minifier, but I have the dependency in my package-lock.json. 
What can I do to export my app to production?

Comment: How does your `index.html` look like ?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states (`parse error`) you have an error in your HTML file. It seems that you forgot to close the quote of the `href` attribute.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcd  n.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css  <------ Missing quote`